File Not Found Exception When Reading a File From Assets Into An ArrayList in Android Studio
I'm trying to read the contents of a text file in my Assets folder into an ArrayList.  I have multiple files to read in, each to their own ArrayList, so I'm trying to create a method I can call to do the reading-in part.  The problem I'm having is I can't seem to get the method to access a file.
I've tried changing the filename to include/not include the file extension, and I've tried testing it with the actual path of the file on my pc and nothing so far has worked.
Here is my code as it stands:
    ArrayList<String> arrayListFiller(ArrayList<String> ray, String filename){
            try{
                File file = new File("assets/" + filename);
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    ray.add(sc.nextLine());
                }
                sc.close();
                return ray;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An IO error occurred while attempting to populate an ArrayList from " + filename);
                return ray;
            }
        }

Then in the onCreate I call the method on each relevant ArrayList, for example for the file Animals.txt to be read into the ArrayList animals:
    animals = arrayListFiller(animals, filenameAnimals);

The app runs fine, it doesn't crash, but in logcat I can see my little error message of "An IO error occurred while attempting to populate an ArrayList from Animals"
This is all inside MainActivity.java as well.  I know I'm not supposed to be using scanner from reading other questions answered here but every time I tried something with bufferedreader it gave me a null pointer exception.  Scanner was the only way I could get the app to run at all.

Try ArrayList<String> arrayListFiller(ArrayList<String> ray, String assetPath){ try (Scanner s = new Scanner(getAssets().open(assetPath)).useDelimiter("\\R")) {ray.addAll(s.tokens().toList());}return ray;}
